# Use an object change to trigger Python script

Tags: python, 3d-cursor

So I'm fairly new to the Blender API, and I have a script that needs to be run every time the 3D cursor is moved. I can get the current location with `bpy.context.scene.cursor_location`, but that's only usable from the script itself.

Can this be used to trigger my script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution would be to use a `scene_update_post` handler.

[Event handler access](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78a_release/bpy.app.handlers.html) in Blender.

```
import bpy
def my_handler(scene):
    cursorLoc = bpy.context.scene.cursor_location
    # do something
    print(cursorLoc)

bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_post.append(my_handler)
```

Run the script once, then your function will be called as soon as the scene updates.

This is highly inefficient and will affect the performance depending on the design of the script. It provides an easy solution though and Blender was always fast enough for me to not notice a difference.

Comment: I read that scene_update_post has recently been depreciated. Do you know what the equivalent is now after Blender 2.80?

Comment: Did you [read this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/140789/30849)?

Comment: Here's a hack solution maybe it helps https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/283247/how-to-trigger-a-script-after-completing-object-transform