# How to drive multiple shape keys based on relative camera position?

Tags: python, animation, drivers

My question is basically an extension of one asked last year: [Drive shape key based on relative camera orientation?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112836/drive-shape-key-based-on-relative-camera-orientation)

They received some great answers but the solutions seem to be only for one shape key and camera angle.

I have a NPR Toon model I've been working on and I would love to be able to associate a camera angle with a specific shape key (like in the aforementioned post), but for multiple angles and shape keys.

I'm aware of a solution using Animation Nodes (https://youtu.be/t9rVg4L8nBU), but I was hoping for a more elegant solution using drivers or python (unfortunately my knowledge of python is little).

This is what I'm hoping to learn how to achieve: https://mobile.twitter.com/MuRo_CG/status/1206902886090735616?s=20

Comment: In that example, it seems like the angle is what's driving the key, not position. The position of the camera is changing, but it seems like the angle is what's actually affecting the keys.

Comment: Oh, yes, I meant camera angle. :)